borders in divs appearing when animating with jquery

Hi, I couldn't find anything on this, so, basicly, when I animate the containers with this:
    
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#startJourneyContainer').click(function() {
        $("#time").animate({color: "white"}, 800);
        $("#containerInside").animate({opacity: '0',left: '-=300px'}, 800);
        $("#containerInsideIniciar").animate({opacity: '1',left: '-=300px',}, 800);
    });
});


.containerInsideIniciar {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 670px;
    width: 310px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    top: 38px;
    opacity: 0;
    /* left: 0px;  */
    left: 310px;  
    background: rgb(34,190,82);
    background: linear-gradient(187deg, rgba(34,190,82,1) 6%, rgba(33,169,196,1) 24%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 55%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: 4;
}


.containerInside {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 670px;
    width: 310px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    top: 38px;
    left: 0px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(white,#deeefa,#deeefa);
}

And, when they move, their borders appear there (in the image), how would I make them not show?

Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

You can use a clip-path on the containerinside element. Set it to inset and add a rounded border radius. See more at MDN on clip-path. I have further explanation in the CSS comments.
I placed a border on the background element for some visual reference on positioning.
For code use in snippet only -> 
1:


#cont {
  /* parent element should have a position of relative so child 
     elements can be positioned relative to its postion on the page. */ 
  position: relative; 
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #555;
}

#img {
  z-index: 2; /* higher index than the clipped background */
}

#iphoneBG-clip {
  position: absolute; /* position set to absolute */
  padding: 5px;
  width: calc(120px - (5px * 2)); /* make your clip element as close to the same size in width/height */
  height: calc(230px - (5px * 2)); /* used a calc with padding calc'd */
  background: red;
  justify-content: center; 
  z-index: 1; /* set z-index lower than the element you are clipping to */
  
   /* clip-path left/right top/bottom then specify 
      round and give a number to apply border-radius on clip-path */
  clip-path: inset( 0% 5% round 16px);   
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1rem;
}

#iphoneBG-without-clip-without-positioning {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 5px;
  width: calc(120px - (5px * 2)); /* make your clip element as close to the same size in width/height */
  height: calc(230px - (5px * 2)); /* used a calc with padding calc'd */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  left: 0;
  background: orange;
  z-index: 1;
  /*clip-path: inset( 0% 5% round 16px); /* clip-path commented out */
}
<div id="cont">
  <div id="iphoneBG-without-clip-without-positioning">non-positioned element with clip-path commented out for reference</div>
  <div id="iphoneBG-clip">Clipped Background positioned with flex</div>
  <img src="https://i.sstatic.net/Ho10NwOy.png" id="img">
</div>



